# When using Mongolite to insert an entry into a collection, how do you get back the ObjectID?

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I'm on a small project where the Mongo database has some collections that have one to many relationships with other collections.

Let's say I have a collection called `Company` which has a 1 to many relationship with `Employee`. In R, if I've just created a company instance, and I did something like `returnValue <- companyCollection$insert(Company)`, I'd like to get a return value that indicates what the `objectId` of the newly inserted company is. I want this because I plan to create `Employee` instances that have a field called `companyId` which would have that company's `objectId` 
 as a field. Is there any way to get the `objectId` returned when inserting 1 entry into a collection using mongolite?

I know if working directly with mongo, you can use `db.collection.insertOne()` to get the object ID back, but I see no such options using the mongolite wrapper for R.

If this is impossible with mongolite, how do you specify '_id' attribute in such a way that when inserting the entry into a collection, mongo treats it as type "ObjectID" rather than "String"? Currently, if I supply my own _id, mongo treats _id as a string rather than an object ID. Mongo compass shows my inserted document id as:

[image: mongo treats supplied _id as "string" rather than "ObjectId"]

rather than this:

[image: The _id generated by mongo, which is actually of type "ObjectId"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a way to get the generated object id when inserting a document into a collection, but I ended up just using a workaround for it. The work around is to have a temporary field in your document that has a UUID it it, and then use that uuid to lookup the object again. After that, you can get the `_id` that mongo generated and delete the temporary field that was created. Here's a function that does that.

```
# an example of a collection
myTableCollection<- mongo("myTable", url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase")

# This is a function to insert a dataframe into mongo collection as a document, 
# and get back the ObjectID that was generated by mongo
storeIntoCollection <- function(document, collection){

    # so create a temporary ID to find the entry in the database again
    temp <- UUIDgenerate()
    document$creationID <- temp


    # insert the DB Object
    returnValue = collection$insert(document)

    # query string to look up object using temp id
    id_string <- paste('{"creationID" : "' , temp , '"}', sep="")

    # Get mongo DB object just inserted
    insertedDocument = collection$find(id_string, field = '{}')

    # delete the temporary 'creationID' field
    update_string <-  paste('{ "$unset" : {"creationID": ""} }', sep="")
    collection$update(id_string, update_string)

    # turn '_id' to 'id'
    colnames(document)[colnames(document)=="_id"] <- "id"

    return(insertedDocument$id)
}
```